# How do you execute a bash script with "system()" when there are spaces in the file path?

Tags: c, linux, bash

I created a simple bash script called "myscript.h" I gave it a .h extensions for reasons that I won't disclose here. This bash script lives in "/var/ftp/something with spaces".

From the terminal, I can type in "/var/ftp/something with spaces/myscript.h" and the script works perfectly.

However, from within my C program, I type in

```
system("/var/ftp/something with spaces/myscript.h")
```

and it complains that "/var/ftp/something" is not found. I've changed my system call to the following with forward slashes:

```
system("/var/ftp/something\ with\ spaces/myscript.h")
```

However, it still complains that "/var/ftp/something" is not found. Assuming I can't change the directory names, how can I get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try adding quotes within the string using the escape sequence \" : 
system("\"/var/ftp/something with spaces/myscript.h\"");

Comment: it's funny to call your bash script with a `.h` extension...

Comment: You can efficiently and robustly run your program with `execl("/var/ftp/something with spaces/myscript.h", NULL)` (with a fork first).  `system()` is for "convenience" and is slower, more fragile and may have security implications.

Comment: Short answer: the backslashes are interpreted by the c-lexer: `'\ '` is  equal to a space. So, you should *double* them, and the shell will see a backslash plus a space. (or: put the whole thing into escaped quotes, using `'\"`or `'\''`, like in one of the answers)

Comment: @Izzo: Because C parses backslashes in double-quoted strings, you actually need to write each backslash as \\. Thus, the backslash-escaped command is `system("/var/ftp/something\\ with\\ spaces/myscript.h")`. In POSIXy systems you can use single quotes, ie. `system("'/var/ftp/something with spaces/myscript.h'")`.

Comment: I think your second atrmpt is nearly there. However you need to escape thr forward slashes, to prevent the compiler interpreting them, and actually make them part of the string.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I agree it is odd, however the platform I'm developing for trips up on loading .sh extensions.

Comment: @thatotherguy I agree. My initial attempt used execl but threw kernel errors outside of my control. This is an alternative attempt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To run a single script, you might avoid the [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) library function (and use lower level system calls like [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)... which are used by the implementation of [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)), or you could *quote* the script name when passing it to [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html).

For more details, read [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

On Linux, [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) is documented to fork a `/bin/sh -c` process. See [sh(1p)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sh.1p.html). And that POSIX shell has some [quoting rules](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html). You might use double-quotes and backslashes appropriately. So you would construct (and perhaps check) the string passed to [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) (perhaps using [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html) or [snprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/snprintf.3.html) with *care*). Be aware that the C compiler also has (different) quoting conventions for [string literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_literal).

In general, you should **avoid [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection)** (imagine a naughty user giving some `a; rm -rf $HOME &;` input as a "directory" name; you don't want to run [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) on the weird 
 `"/var/ftp/a; rm -rf $HOME &;/myscript.h"` string)

In your particular case, I recommend using [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) (perhaps thru some carefully choosen [exec(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html) function), [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)... appropriately. This has the slight advantage to avoid depending on and running `/bin/sh` so could be slightly faster (by a millisecond).

Understand more the role of an [Unix shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_shell); for example, read about the various [shell expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html) in `bash` (they are similar to those mandated by POSIX `sh`) and be aware of [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). See [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html)

Answer (score 0):

Note that you're adding quotes when running from the shell.  You need to do the same here.  Add quotes to the path name you're sending to `system`:

```
system("\"/var/ftp/something with spaces/myscript.h\"")
```

Comment: I don't know about Linux, but that trick doesn't work on windows.

Comment: It does work on Linux, but some characters (backslashes, newlines, double-quotes, ...) might need to be escaped

Answer (score 0):

This should work with gcc version 5.4.0

```
system("\'\'/var/ftp/something\\ with\\ spaces/myscript.h\'\'");
```

Answer (score -1):

Just put the filename inside single quotes

```
system("rm '/var/ftp/something with spaces/myscript.h'")
```

Comment: Not as simple if the file path contains quotes. And `rm` is useless inside a `system`, use [unlink(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html)

Comment: @thatotherguy: No, `unlink` is the system call used by  `/bin/rm` (for files)

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. Yes, `system("rm foo")` is a bad idea and should be replaced with `unlink("foo")`